# Importing DB with index without reindexing

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration, impdp

I want to import a DB using impdp. I would like to import the INDEX NAMES and after that, rebuild it manually.

I used the option

```
EXCLUDE=index
```

but then I can't find the index in the table `all_indexes`
Is there a way to import the index without build them, and build them manually afterwards ?

Comment: Do a second import for just the indexes afterwards? Why do you want to do this though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import all tables and data with following parameters

SQLFILE=create_index.sql include=index

This parameter doesn't create any index but create a sql file with all create index sql statements. Using this file you can create index manually after finishing table and data import.

Answer (score 0):

you can also export/ import only metadata, this will import only table & index structures.

CONTENT=metadata_only